# Does WSO2 ESB support SOAP attachments

Tags: wso2-esb

I am looking into WSO2 ESB for our integration need. One of the scenario requires use of SOAP with attachment. Does anyone know if it support SOAP with attachments? It is not clear from their documentation.

If no, how difficult is it to extend their existing functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 is based on Axis2, which supports SwA and MTOM attachements. Check the Sample 51 article in order to see it in action:

https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136025